# Is there a framework for distributing browser automation testing over a cluster of EC2 instances?

Tags: browser-automation, distributed-testing

I am aiming to simulate a large number of 'real users' hitting and realistically using our site at the same time, and ensuring they can all get through their use cases.  I am looking for a framework that combines some EC2 grid management with a web automation tool (such as GEB/WATIR).  Ideal 'pushbutton' operation would do all of this:

1. Start up a configurable number of EC2 instances (using a specified
   AMI preconfigured with my browser automation framework and test
   scripts)
2. Start the web automation framework test(s) running on all of them,
   in parallel.  I guess they would have to be headless.
3. Wait for completion
4. Aggregate results
5. Shut down EC2 instances.

Answer (score 0):

While not a framework per se, I've been really happy with http://loader.io/

It has an API for your own custom integration, reporting and analytics for analysis.

PS. I'm not affiliated with them, just a happy customer.

However, in my experience, you need to do both load testing and actual client testing. Even loader.io will only hit your service from a handful of hosts. And, it skips a major part (the client-side performance from a number of different clients' browsers).

This video has more on that topic:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Il4swGfTOSM&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0):

[BrowserMob](https://home.wpm.neustar.biz/) used to offer such service. Looks like they got acquired.